# Confusion in least action in the following situation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

[image]

I understand that when electric field is applied normal to the surface of a conductor the net electric field inside the conductor is zero.

But as shown in the diagram above, if electric field is not normal to the surface of a conductor, I see two possiblity of induced electric field shown in dotted lines.

What I don't understand is whether the induced electric field will align to nullify applied electric field so that it achieves least energy or will the electric field will follow least path which won't cancel the applied electric field entirely?

So both are least action situations, which will have the priority? How do we decide?

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field is always perpendicular to the surface of a conductor.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that. So for any type of surface the field will align itself to be normal to the surface.

Comment: No. Just for conductors. The charge resides entirely on the surface of a conductor and moves freely about, so if the field is not normal to the surface the charges will feel a force tangent to the surface and will move about on the surface. This will continue as long as the field is not normal so it is not a stable scenario. The charges stop moving when there is no more force tangent to the surface, i.e., field is normal at each point.

Comment: Thank you for providing a good explanation.

Comment: inside the conductor, the (balanced, not excess) charges will move about until the field is completely canceled inside.  this is for a similar reason as the charges move about on the surface. the charges are free to move about so if there is a field inside the charges will continue to move.  they will only stop when the field inside is zero.